What is the authenticity of this narration by Umar RA?
It is narrated by by Hanafi scholar Abu Yusuf that Umar RA stated:

Have you considered, if we take them [as slaves] and share them out, what will be left for Muslims who come after us? By God, the Muslims would not find a man to talk to and profit from his labors. The Muslims of our day will eat [from the work of] these people as long as they live, and when we and they die, our sons will eat their sons forever, as long as they remain, for they are slaves to the people of the religion of Islam as long as the religion of Islam shall prevail.

What is the authenticity of this statement? Likewise, what does it mean?

Alhamdulillah,
The full narration in Arabic can be found in Kitab al Kharaaj by Abu Yusuf p.154-155.
Visit https://app.turath.io/book/26333?page=159
Regarding its authenticity, it is has no isnad (i.e., without a chain).
I will provide a summary and an explanation of its meaning below.
Abu Ubaidah wrote to Umar informing him about the defeat of the polytheists and the conquest Allah had granted the Muslims. He mentioned the peace treaties he had made with the dhimmis (non-Muslim citizens of the Islamic state) and asked Umar whether to distribute the conquered lands, cities, trees and crops among the Muslims as spoils of war.
Umar consulted the Companions of the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ and then responded based on the verses of the Quran regarding the disposal of spoils of war (fay') (Al Hashr:7-8). He instructed Abu Ubaidah:

The conquered lands, cities and their inhabitants are not to be divided among the Muslims as spoils, as per the treaties.
Rather, the dhimmis should pay jizyah according to their financial capacity.
The Muslims have no choice but to uphold these treaties and levy only the jizyah, as Allah has commanded fighting the disbelievers until they pay jizyah (Al Tawbah:29).
4.If the Muslims were to divide and enslave the dhimmis, they would be consumed until they are finished and the Muslims would not find anyone to profit from his labors. Instead, these people should remain the custodians and cultivators of the land as they know it best which will allow for the current Muslims to eat from the labor of these people as long as they live, and then so on among the future generations who will eat from the work of the descendents of these people.
5.The jizyah should be distributed among the Muslims, while the dhimmis remain the cultivators and residents of the land.
The Muslims must not oppress or harm the dhimmis or seize their wealth unlawfully, and must honor the terms they pledged.

Inshallah this helps you make sense of the quote.
And Allah knows best!

May Allah bless you akhi.

Do you happen to know which battle or campaign this was after?
